# Error creating bean with name 'offerRepository': Invocation of init method failed, Spring data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have few classes as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
public class Offer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "title", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private Boolean active;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private ReechargeInfo reechargeInfo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<ReturnInfo> returnInfos = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "offer_sub_category",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="offers_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="sub_categories_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<SubCategory> subCategories = new HashSet<>();

}
```

ReechargeInfo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reecharge_info")
public class ReechargeInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "reecharge_info_circle",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="reecharge_infos_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="circles_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Circle> circles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I'm trying to select offers as below using spring data jpa

```
@Query("select offer from Offer offer left join fetch offer.subCategories subCategories where offer.active =:active and subCategories.name =:subCategoryName and reechargeInfo.circles.id=:circleId)
List<Offer> findAllToCalculateCashbackForMobile(@Param("active") boolean active, @Param("subCategoryName") String subCategoryName, 
        @Param("circleId") Long circleId);
```

Getting the following errors:

```
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'offerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.creatives.apsstr.cashbackcalculator.repository.OfferRepository.findAllToCalculateCashbackForMobile(boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 22 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.creatives.apsstr.cashbackcalculator.repository.OfferRepository.findAllToCalculateCashbackForMobile(boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'reechargeInfo.circles.id' [select offer from com.creatives.apsstr.cashbackcalculator.domain.Offer offer left join fetch offer.operatingSystems left join fetch offer.cities left join fetch offer.states left join fetch offer.countries left join fetch offer.subCategories subCategories left join fetch offer.applicableServiceProviders applicableServiceProviders left join fetch offer.variations where offer.active =:active and subCategories.name =:subCategoryName and reechargeInfo.circles.id=:circleId]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy402.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 46 common frames omitted`
```

Comment: The error message says `Invalid path: 'reechargeInfo.circles.id'`. Indeed, the `reechargeInfo` is not a valid "top level" variable in the query. You probably meant `offer.reechargeInfo.circles.id=:circleId`.

Comment: I attempted **offer.reechargeInfo.circles.id=:circleId**, Now i'm getting this error    `Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [offer0_.idoffer0_.reecharge_info_idreechargeInfo.circles] with element property reference [id]`

Comment: Collections need to be dereferenced in JPQL if the query needs to operate on one or more property of collection elements; example: `SELECT r FROM ReechargeInfo r INNER JOIN r.circles c WHERE c.id = ?`.

Comment: @manish oh yeas.. Thank you.. Will try this..

Comment: @manish It worked..